# Cannot use HttpHeaderSecurityFilter for specific apps in Tomcat 8, got ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter

Tags: java, tomcat, catalina

I want in some specific apps to enable HttpHeaderSecurityFilter (I might have some unsecure applications at the same server).

I've edited web.xml of one application (not the tomcat/conf/web.xml file to add this filter):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>hstsMaxAgeSeconds</param-name>
       <param-value>31536000</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

But I've got the error message when running from Tomcat 8.0.9.0. This happened in development enviroment, this Tomcat was installed with Netbeans 8.0.1.

```
08-Sep-2016 09:35:37.108 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter httpHeaderSecurity
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:531)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4603)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:455)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1496)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1437)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:884)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:335)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What could be the reason Tomcat is displaying ClassNotFoundExpceiotn for 
org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter, since this exists since Tomcat 7?

Comment: Following the line `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter`, my question is does  the class exist in your classpath? Is there a `.jar` which contains that Class in the package `org.apache.catalina.filters`. If not, this most likely is why you're getting this error.

Comment: It seems that feature was added in Tomcat 8 in

Add: 54618: Add a new HttpHeaderSecurityFilter that adds the Strict-Transport-Security, X-Frame-Options and X-Content-Type-Options HTTP headers to the response. (markt)

And Netbeans embedded version I was using was 8.0.9, I guess that was the problem.

Comment: @Arty I am facing the same issue. Where exactly in my classpath do I check for this file?

Comment: @SandeepanNath check your Tomcat version, it should be higher than 8. This file exists in apache-tomcat-8.0.27/lib/catalina.jar